# tree expand collapse not working in "expandable and collapsible content of a button "

Tags: javascript, html, tree

tree structure which uses another script source files are working very well for hierarchy i am using.

but when i am using same tree structure content in "expandable collapsible content" of a button then problem is occurring as : if i use java script code of tree structure then expand collapse feature of button is not working but expand collapse feature of tree is working. When i dont use java script code of tree structure then expand collapse feature of button is working and needless to say that expand collapse feature of tree is not working.

i am attaching code of button and its java-script code .....

```js
// button JS code ...... 

<script>

(function(){
  ('#demo').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    ('button1').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show');
  })
  ('#demo').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    ('button1').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Hide');
  })
})

(function(){
  ('#demo').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    ('button2').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show');
  })
  ('#demo').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    ('button2').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Hide');
  })
})
</script>


// tree structure JS code ......

          <script src="HTML5 Admin_files/jquery.min.js">
          </script>
          <script src="HTML5 Admin_files/bootstrap.min.js">
          </script>
          <script src="HTML5 Admin_files/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
          </script>
          <script src="HTML5 Admin_files/jstree.min.js">
          </script>
          <script src="HTML5 Admin_files/stackers.js">
          </script>
```

```html
<div class="box-footer">

                <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show 1
            </button>

<div id="demo1" class="collapse">
   <div class="tree">
            <ul>
            <li class="parent_li">
              <span class="badge green" title="Collapse this branch">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open">
                </i> Parent
            </span> 
              <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
              </a>
            <ul>
                <li class="parent_li">
                  <span class="badge red" title="Collapse this branch">
                    <i class="fa fa-minus-sign">
                    </i> Child
                </span> 
                  <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
                  </a>
                  <ul>
                    <li style="display: list-item;">
                      <span class="badge orange" title="Collapse this branch">
                      <i class="fa fa-leaf">
                      </i> Akhil
                    </span> 
                      <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
                      </a>
                      <ul>
                        <li class="parent_li" style="display: list-item;">
                          <span class="badge red" title="Collapse this branch">
                          <i class="fa fa-minus-sign">
                          </i> Great Grand Child
                        </span> 
                          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
                          </a>
                            <ul>
                              <li style="display: list-item;">
                                  <span class="badge green" title="Collapse this branch">
                                  <i class="fa fa-leaf">
                                  </i> Great great Grand Child
                                </span> 
                                  <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="display: list-item;">
                                <span class="badge green" title="Collapse this branch">
                                <i class="fa fa-leaf">
                                </i> Great great Grand Child
                              </span> 
                                <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
                                </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li style="display: list-item;">
                          <span class="badge red" title="Collapse this branch">
                          <i class="fa fa-leaf">
                          </i> Great Grand Child
                        </span> 
                          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li style="display: list-item;">
                          <span class="badge red" title="Collapse this branch">
                            <i class="fa fa-leaf">
                            </i> Great Grand Child
                        </span> 
                          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
                          </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
              
                    <li style="display: list-item;">
                      <span class="badge orange" title="Collapse this branch">
                      <i class="fa fa-leaf">
                      </i> Grand Child
                    </span> 
                      <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
                      </a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <li class="parent_li">  
            <span class="badge red" title="Collapse this branch">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-sign">
          </i> Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
            <span class="badge orange" title="Collapse this branch">
              <i class="fa fa-leaf">
          </i> Grand Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
      </li>
          <li class="parent_li">
            <span class="badge orange" title="Collapse this branch">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-sign">
          </i> Grand Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li class="parent_li" style="display: list-item;">
            <span class="badge green" title="Collapse this branch">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-sign">
          </i> Great Grand Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
            <span class="badge orange" title="Collapse this branch">
            <i class="fa fa-leaf">
          </i> Great great Grand Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
      </li>
          <li style="display: list-item;">
            <span class="badge orange" title="Collapse this branch">
            <i class="fa fa-leaf">
          </i> Great great Grand Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li style="display: list-item;">
            <span class="badge green" title="Collapse this branch">
            <i class="fa fa-leaf">
          </i> Great Grand Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
      </li>
          <li style="display: list-item;">
           <span class="badge green" title="Collapse this branch">
            <i class="fa fa-leaf">
          </i> Great Grand Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
          <li>
            <span class="badge orange" title="Collapse this branch">
            <i class="fa fa-leaf">
          </i> Grand Child
      </span> 
          <a href="">Anyhing can go here!
          </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
            
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

 </br>
</br>

                <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show 2
</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
  <ol class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Wa</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Adurer</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Mae</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```